# why $\sum_{k=1}^{p^n-1}(-1)^{k+1}x^k\binom{p^n}{k}\equiv\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k+1}x^{p^{n-1}k}\binom{p}{k}\pmod {p^2}$

Tags: number-theory

Following is number theory book,it is clear use Kummer and Lucas  theorem,But I can't understand this step?

> Let $p$ is prime number,show that
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^{p^n-1}(-1)^{k+1}x^k\binom{p^n}{k}\equiv\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k+1}x^{k\cdot p^{n-1}}\cdot\binom{p}{k}\pmod {p^2}$$

Comment: it is said use Kummer and Lucas theorem,How to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $0<k<p^n$ with $p$ an odd prime. If $p^{n-1}$ does not divide $k$ then
$$\binom{p^n}{k}=\frac{p^n}{k}\binom{p^n-1}{k-1}\equiv 0 \pmod{p^2}$$
If $p^{n-1}$  divides $k$ then $k=p^{n-1}j$ with $0< j<p$ and 
$$\binom{p^n}{k}=\binom{p^n}{p^{n-1}j}=\frac{p^n}{p^{n-1}j}\binom{p^n-1}{p^{n-1}j-1}\equiv \frac{p}{j}\binom{p-1}{j-1}=\binom{p}{j} \pmod{p^2}$$
because by Lucas' Theorem,
$$\binom{p^n-1}{p^{n-1}j-1}=
\binom{(p^{n-1}-1)p+p-1}{(p^{n-2}j-1)p+p-1}\\\equiv \binom{p^{n-1}-1}{p^{n-2}j-1}\binom{p-1}{p-1}=\binom{p^{n-1}-1}{p^{n-2}j-1}\equiv\binom{p^{n-2}-1}{p^{n-3}j-1}\equiv \cdots \equiv\binom{p-1}{j-1} \pmod{p}.$$
Hence, 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p^n-1}(-1)^{k+1}x^k\binom{p^n}{k}\equiv\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{p^{n-1}j+1}x^{p^{n-1}j}\cdot\binom{p}{p^{n-1}j}\\
\equiv\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{j+1}x^{ p^{n-1}j}\cdot\binom{p}{j}\pmod {p^2}.$$